# IntelliJ IDE - FileNotFound exception from root project directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fileinputstream

I used an ObjectOutputStream to write an object to a file in the same directory as my project's .iml file. The file exists. For some reason, I can't read it using a FileInputStream. I recieve a FileNotFound exception at line 2.
My code is as follows:

```
File sceneFile=new File("scene.dodge");
FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(sceneFile);
ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(fin);
return (Scene)(in.readObject());
```

I've made sure the file scene.dodge is in the project root directory. Any suggestions? I've tried messing around with compiler resource patterns, but I have no idea if that'll do anything. I'm simply stumped.

Answer (score 0):

To read the file from the current directory you need to use [ClassLoader#
getResource method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).
Load the file like this

```
URL dodgeSceneURL = classLoader.getResource("scene.dodge");
File sceneFile = new File(dodgeSceneURL.toURI());
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(sceneFile);
```

Comment: I tried: URL sceneURL=Scene.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
For some reason, this still gave a nullpointerexception

Comment: Where is the classLoader instantiated? I'm afraid I simply don't understand this.

Comment: @TinFellow `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` thats how you get the classLoader, I didn't posted the entire code because that's not relevant.